# how to enable tpm auto provisioning in azure window 10 update 1809 virtual machine?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-iot-edge

I  have azure  virtual machine(windows 10 update 1809 and vm size is Standard D2s v3 (2 vcpus, 8 GB memory)) in which developing solution for iotedge with device provisioning service using TPM. Unable to auto provisioning using Enable-TpmAutoProvisioning powershell command.

Opened the powershell run as admin in azure virtual machine(Window 10 update 1809), Run Enable-TpmAutoProvisioning command in powershell

```
PS C:\Users\dev> Enable-TpmAutoProvisioning
```

got error message which is given below

```
TpmPresent                : False
TpmReady                  : False
ManufacturerId            : 0
ManufacturerIdTxt         :
ManufacturerVersion       :
ManufacturerVersionFull20 :
ManagedAuthLevel          : Full
OwnerAuth                 :
OwnerClearDisabled        : True
AutoProvisioning          : NotDefined
LockedOut                 : False
LockoutHealTime           :
LockoutCount              :
LockoutMax                :
SelfTest                  :



PS C:\Users\dev> TpmReady           : False
TpmReady : The term 'TpmReady' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ TpmReady           : False
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (TpmReady:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\dev> TpmPresent         : True
TpmPresent : The term 'TpmPresent' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ TpmPresent         : True
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (TpmPresent:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\dev> ManagedAuthLevel   : Full
ManagedAuthLevel : The term 'ManagedAuthLevel' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ManagedAuthLevel   : Full
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ManagedAuthLevel:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\dev> OwnerAuth          : OwnerClearDisabled : True
OwnerAuth : The term 'OwnerAuth' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ OwnerAuth          : OwnerClearDisabled : True
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (OwnerAuth:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\dev> AutoProvisioning   : Enabled
AutoProvisioning : The term 'AutoProvisioning' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ AutoProvisioning   : Enabled
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (AutoProvisioning:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\dev> LockedOut          : False
LockedOut : The term 'LockedOut' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ LockedOut          : False
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (LockedOut:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\dev> SelfTest           : {191, 191, 245, 191...}
At line:1 char:43
+ SelfTest           : {191, 191, 245, 191...}
+                                           ~
You must provide a value expression following the '..' operator.
At line:1 char:43
+ SelfTest           : {191, 191, 245, 191...}
+                                           ~
Unexpected token '.' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:43
+ SelfTest           : {191, 191, 245, 191...}
+                                           ~
Missing expression after '.' in pipeline element.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression

PS C:\Users\dev>


In Azure virtual machine(Windows 10 update 1809), After running 
PS C:\Users\dev> Enable-TpmAutoProvisioning

output should be
TpmPresent                : True
TpmReady                  : True
ManufacturerId            : 1229346816
ManufacturerIdTxt         : IFX
ManufacturerVersion       : 7.63
ManufacturerVersionFull20 : 7.63.13.6400

ManagedAuthLevel          : Full
OwnerAuth                 :
OwnerClearDisabled        : False
AutoProvisioning          : Enabled
LockedOut                 : False
LockoutHealTime           : 10 minutes
LockoutCount              : 0
LockoutMax                : 31
SelfTest                  : {}
```

Comment: Hi @dreamgeek, have you found a way to do it on Azure?

Answer (score -1):

The error messages are not because of `Enable-TpmAutoProvisioning` command. You seem to have pasted some extra text at the end of the command. Please ensure you run the command properly.

For example:

```
PS C:\Users\dev> TpmReady           : False
TpmReady : The term 'TpmReady' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ TpmReady           : False
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (TpmReady:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

You seem to have pasted `PS C:\Users\dev> TpmReady           : False` incorrectly in the powershell window.

Please just run `Enable-TpmAutoProvisioning`